# Query to rename file path if it match in filepath table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

In the image I have filepath and parent_path columns, The requirement is if my string is contains in filepath  then replace with new string and in parent path too.

Example : `E:\Images\Apple_icon.jpg`  search for "Images" if contains replace with "MyImages", like this=> `E:\MyImages\Apple_icon.jpg`

[image]

Comment: you can use replace function

Comment: can you try my ans ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    update tableName set FILEPATH=REPLACE(FILEPATH,'E:\Images\','E:\MyImages\') ,
PARENT_PATH=REPLACE(PARENT_PATH,'E:\Images','E:\MyImages')
```